# iOS: 'PebbleKit/PebbleKit.h' file not found Issue

Tags: ios, frameworks, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am working with a project which includes Pebble Kit framework. I have two targets in the same project. When I run project on device, it works fine. But as I archive the same project to create an IPA, it shows below error,

Lexical or preprocessor error in PebbleWatch.h file,

'PebbleKit/PebbleKit.h' file not found.

I cleaned project multiple times & re included the same frameworks in the project by selecting reference two both the projects. How this can be resolved ?

Comment: select view controller select ->show finder and find the file and add

Comment: which file ? PebbleKit.h ?

Comment: in your project anyOne viewController….select and ---> show in finder then search the Pebble.h

Comment: nice keep thinking positive and dig the code or search SO post's….