# 'PebbleKit/PebbleKit.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project I am using pebble kit framework but when try to build then this error came,

```
Lexical or preprocessor error in PebbleWatch.h file,    
'PebbleKit/PebbleKit.h' file not found.
```

what should I do ?

Comment: Downvoted: no research effort

Comment: I tried. Thats why i am here.

Comment: Help I needed nuthing else.

Comment: @John, read the 3rd comment in this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098798/ios-pebblekit-pebblekit-h-file-not-found-issue

Comment: You should learn C first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like either your .h file is missing or path for that framework is missing. try to re add the `PebbleWatch.h` file again or try to set the path for that file or library in Build Settings.